# Weird Exception when Livewallpaper is set in Android

Tags: android, game-engine, live-wallpaper, andengine

```
04-24 13:30:59.312: VERBOSE/RenderScript(6044): RS Thread exited
04-24 13:30:59.320: ERROR/libEGL(6044): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
04-24 13:30:59.335: WARN/WallpaperService(6044): Ignoring updateSurface: destroyed
04-24 13:30:59.335: WARN/WindowManager(108): Window android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy@408968d0 is already added
04-24 13:30:59.355: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6083): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 23K, 52% free 2598K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 55ms
04-24 13:30:59.425: DEBUG/GLWallpaperService(6083): onSurfaceDestroyed()
04-24 13:30:59.496: WARN/InputQueue-JNI(6044): Input channel is not initialized.
04-24 13:30:59.515: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(6044): Shutting down VM
04-24 13:30:59.539: WARN/dalvikvm(6044): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to register input channel.  Check logs for details.
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.view.InputQueue.nativeRegisterInputChannel(Native Method)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.view.InputQueue.registerInputChannel(InputQueue.java:92)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.updateSurface(WallpaperService.java:521)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:904)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-24 13:30:59.640: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I was developing a Livewallpaper which uses a open-source game engine called Andengine(andengine.org), it works fine now except sometimes when user set my Livewallpaper as wall paper, an Exception will be thrown saying "Failed to register input channel.  Check logs for details.", but the werid thing is the Livewallpaper still works and did not exit.

Any idea what maybe causing this problem , or how I can fix it?

Comment: (1) Did you check "the logs"? (2) Do you have a second round in the stack trace that starts with "caused by:"?

Comment: @Aleadam No there is only one round of stack trace. And the only logs I found related to this issue is " call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)" as I list above

Comment: @Aleadam also " Input channel is not initialized"

Comment: @Aleadam I found out it was because I was using launcher pro for test, it doesn't release the hardware OpenGL ES was currently using when the user clicks "Set wallpaper" button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I could only find that the `InputQueue` "provides a mechanism for an application to receive incoming input events.  Currently only usable from native code".

Check the `GLSurfaceView` class in andengine. That may give you a clue of what is wrong with your wallpaper

You may also want to check why this is happening:

```
04-24 13:30:59.320: ERROR/libEGL(6044): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured out it has something to do with Launcher Pro, which didn't release the hardware after user set me as wallpaper fast enough. If I change to android original Home Screen the Exception is gone.

Comment: Launcher Pro has its issues. I've seen some weird bugs with it (although IMHO is still the best launcher out there). I would consider sending them a bug report so they might try to to fix it and release the hw sooner.

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure what the cause is, but it's definitely their issue, so I'll send them a bug report.