# "Failed to register input channel" - what is this caused by and how to fix this?

Tags: android, user-interface, forceclose

I've been getting the following error, reported via Market developer console by the users of my app:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to register input channel. Check logs for details.
    at android.view.InputQueue.nativeRegisterInputChannel(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputQueue.registerInputChannel(InputQueue.java:92)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:568)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:465)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
    at my.program.MyActivity.handleFailure(Unknown Source)
    at my.program.MyActivity$RunFailed.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Italicized lines are part of my code. The code in question just creates and shows a dialog. It is run from a `Runnable` posted to a `Handler`. Everything should be happening in the GUI thread (that's why `Handler` is used).

I don't know how to debug this. I haven't experienced this problem myself, and all I have is just a bunch of automated reports. Google shows up a couple of threads on this exact problem, but no answers (except a hint of this being an Android 2.3.3-specific problem).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be a Launcher Pro issue.  LP is a home replacement.  It appears Launcher Pro does not release some resources as it should.  Check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768857/weird-exception-when-livewallpaper-is-set-in-android)

Comment: Hey Phobos, Can you please tell me how can I shortly handle this?

Comment: Did, anyone found the solution.