# Failed to register input channel - live wallpaper

Tags: android, runtime-error, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

I encountered similar problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701660/failed-to-register-input-channel-what-is-this-caused-by-and-how-to-fix-this). 

The crash report is from Google Play and I can't reproduce it by myself. I tried to download Launcher Pro but that wasn't causing any troubles.

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to register input channel. Check logs for details.
at android.view.InputQueue.nativeRegisterInputChannel(Native Method)
at android.view.InputQueue.registerInputChannel(InputQueue.java:92)
at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.updateSurface(WallpaperService.java:534)
at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.attach(WallpaperService.java:670)
at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:898)
at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```