# Failed to unregister input channel

Tags: android, runtimeexception

In one of my marketplace apps, I'm seeing a few reports of these from the wild from time to time, and can't determine why they are being thrown.  I'm not doing anything that I would consider unusual in my app.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to unregister input channel.  status=-22
    at android.view.InputQueue.nativeUnregisterInputChannel(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputQueue.unregisterInputChannel(InputQueue.java:119)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:2471)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:4030)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm seeing plenty of hits for "Failed to *register* input channel", but none for *unregister*, hence the reason for this question.

I tried searching but came up with only this from the AOSP tree as the exception origin:

```
from: aosp-frameworks-base / core / jni / android_view_InputQueue.cpp

static void android_view_InputQueue_nativeUnregisterInputChannel(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz,
        jobject inputChannelObj) {
    status_t status = gNativeInputQueue.unregisterInputChannel(env, inputChannelObj);

    if (status) {
        String8 message;
        message.appendFormat("Failed to unregister input channel.  status=%d", status); <-- POSSIBLY THROWING THIS EXCEPTION
        jniThrowRuntimeException(env, message.string());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found what caused that error? And a solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7701822/2628278