# Any way to ensure an Android live wallpaper gets an OpenGL ES context?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, live-wallpaper

According to [this StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768857/weird-exception-when-livewallpaper-is-set-in-android), certain third-party Android launchers/home screens might not release the 3D OpenGL-ES resources when launching a live wallpaper. This can cause the live wallpaper to crash, making it appear from the user's perspective that the live wallpaper is buggy.

Is there any way to program an Android live wallpaper to make sure that it is granted an OpenGL-ES context?

To phrase the question even more broadly, is there any way to program an Android app/wallpaper so that this error never occurs:

```
"ERROR/libEGL(6044): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context"
```

I assume it might be dangerous to snatch the OpenGL-ES context from another application -- if this is even possible. As an alternative, is there any way to request the context, and then just wait for it to be granted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the OpenGL ES spec](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/eglMakeCurrent.html):

> Use eglGetCurrentContext, eglGetCurrentDisplay, and
>   eglGetCurrentSurface to query the current rendering context and
>   associated display connection and surfaces.

The linked documented is for the `eglMakeCurrent` function, which *should* request GL context. Use the following to query if the context is free:

```
EGL10 egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
EGLContext eglc = egl.eglGetCurrentContext();
if(eglc == egl.EGL_NO_CONTEXT){
    Log.d("OpenGLESTag","No context");
}
```

Comment: You may be able to call egl.makeCurrent using the EGL Display parameter from eglGetDisplay(egl.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY) but I'm not sure what would happen when used in conjunction with a Surface object (SurfaceView, GLSurfaceView, Canvas, etc).